# Facebook app posting to timeline not home screen

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app. It allows users to post some data through the app. I have used the following code:

```
$facebook->api("/me/feed", 'post', 
array('message'=> 'Hello',
      'link'=> 'The link goes here',
      'picture'=> 'URL to picture',
      'name'=> 'Something',
      'caption'=> 'Some Caption',
      'description'=> 'Comment',));
```

The above piece of code is posting the message to User timeline. However, it does not appear on the home screen (The screen that appears as soon as a user logs in).

Please let me know if I have missed some necessary configuration. Thanks.

Comment: It will be visible to your friends feed. Dont worry about that

Comment: Thanks. But its not visible. Unless they click on my profile and go to my timeline.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force a story onto the Newsfeed of friends. Facebook's algorithms will determine if the post is relevant to each individual friend, and will insert that post into his or her newsfeed if it is. There's absolutely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me explain my scenario a bit more in detail. Say my friend posts something from the application, it appears in his timeline as well as home screen. When I log-in, I will be taken to my home screen and I see that my friend has posted something, and there is a link available as well. I click on the link and I will be taken to the application. I post it through the application and it now appears only in my timeline. It does not appear in my home screen. So my friends wont be able to see it unless they click on my name and go to my timeline.

Comment: False. Your timeline and newsfeed are not the same thing. Post on the timeline, and it becomes eligible for newsfeed. But it is not guaranteed to hit newsfeed. Only if the algorithm determines its interesting for X person.

Comment: Thanks. If I am not wrong in understanding what you meant, $facebook->api("/me/feed"....) may or may not post to newsfeed depending on the algorithm and there is no way I can control it. So there is always a change that it might go to timeline and at times to userfeed.

Comment: No. /me/feed is the users timeline. When you post to /me/feed it will ALWAYS go on their timeline. The NewsFeeds searches through posts in the Timeline to see what's interesting.

Comment: So, there is no way to guarantee that what's in the time WILL always appear in the NewsFeeds. And it's not something I can control.

Comment: Correct. Kinda like I've been saying the past 4 comments. ;)